# What's [paragon-tier] all about?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a tag for [paragon-tier](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paragon-tier) with seven questions. It's got no usage guidance nor wiki, and I don't know the system at all.

Can someone describe it and edit the tag guidance?

Is it related to/synonymous with [paragon-path](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/paragon-path), a tag in the same system whose excerpt seems to describe a tier?

Comment: VTC duplicate: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/7322/15469

Comment: Duplicates can't be marked across sites. Besides, a question like this about how to manage tags is off topic on Main, so it can't be a duplicate of an on-topic Main question.

Answer (score 11):

They're very close companions but not quite synonymous.

D&D 4e introduced the paragon tier concept to describe a level range (11-20). We've also got paragon paths, which are bundles of skills & benefits a D&D 4e character obtains over the course of the paragon tier.

So we've got questions about paragon paths, but also questions not specifically about paragon paths but about things during that level range (e.g. [How to build a Thief in Paragon tier](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8244/how-to-build-a-thief-in-paragon-tier), [What Paragon-Tier modules can I use to showcase the Underdark?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55590/what-paragon-tier-modules-can-i-use-to-showcase-the-underdark), [How can I view Paragon Tier feats in the Character Builder?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/29650/how-can-i-view-paragon-tier-feats-in-the-character-builder)).

It's weird and they have a significant overlap but I'd leave them separate since they're fundamentally separate game concepts. I've added some usage guidance to both tags.

Answer (score 1):

The paragon tier is the range of character levels from 11 to 20.

The paragon path is a specialization of the class that gives the character some extra features and powers on top of those coming from the base class. The path gets chosen at character level 11 and gives its last feature or power at character level 20.